# SignalR Cross Domain with autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, autofac

I try to use SignalR Cross Domain with autofac.
I didn't success to use it from other domain.

Here is my code:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            SetAutofacContainerSignalR(app);
        }

        private void SetAutofacContainerSignalR(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // STANDARD SIGNALR SETUP:

            // Get your HubConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
            // rather than using GlobalHost.
            var config = new HubConfiguration();

            // Register your SignalR hubs.
            builder.RegisterHubs(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            //All builder.RegisterType

            // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
            var container = builder.Build();
            config.Resolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

            // OWIN SIGNALR SETUP:

            // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the standard SignalR middleware.
            app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
            //app.MapSignalR("/signalr", config);

            app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
                var hubConfiguration = config;
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
        }
    }
```

This is the row that I think I have to change

```
var hubConfiguration = config;
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does it work without Autofac?

Comment: Yes, it's work without Autofac

Comment: And what specifically doesn't work with Autofac?

Comment: I don't success sending function to clients, don't get function to server etc